# When should you check for errors using "if" , and when should you use exceptions?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, conditional-statements

When do you use each? I find that I'm using if's a lot more than exceptions. It seems like I'm catching the exceptions using my "ifs", before I even get them.  There are ifs all over my code.

Comment: This has been asked countless times (2739582, 1152541, 1313812).  Between this question, your question 4557577 (and no doubt countless others), and your now over *eight hundred questions*, it seems like you're something of a question spammer.

Answer (score 4):

[EAFP: Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp)

It is common Python coding style to assume the existence of valid keys or attributes and catch exceptions if the assumption proves false.

This contrasts with the [LBYL (Look before you leap)](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl) style common to many other languages such as C.

**Update 1**

Of course, you must ensure you *handle* any caught exceptions and not just silently ignore them otherwise you're going to waste a lot of time debugging! `pass` is probably not what you are looking for!

**Update 2**

You should catch the **specific exceptions** that you are *expecting* to be `raise`-d, whether they are [built-in exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#module-exceptions) or otherwise.

Comment: I put generic try: except Exceptione, : print e pass Is that oK?

Comment: @TIMEX: There is no generic answer here. How you handle the exception depends on what processing you were doing when the it was `raise` -d. That said `pass` is very rarely what you want!

Comment: It is worth noting that using exception handleing versus `if` statements tells the reader of your code something about what you expect to happen. An `if` statement implies that there is a sizeable chance of the condition being either `True` or `False`, while `try`/`except` implies the handleing of edge cases. So, while EAFP may be idomatic python, there is room for interpretation in a given case. Also, you should almost never use generic `except Exception`.

Comment: Absolutely, @Wilduck. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @TIMEX - If you do that, when someone presses Control-C you will merrily inform them that they generated an exception and continue cheerfully on your way, thereby greatly irritating them.  Also, if someone calls `sys.exit` somewhere that makes it to your exception handler, you will also inform people that there was a `SystemExit`, then continue merrily on your way.  So, in short, you shouldn't catch the generic `Exception`, and you definitely shouldn't just `pass` if you do.

Answer (score 2):

Try catch statements are designed to handle serious errors and particularly for connecting to outside service such as a web service, Database, web Request and etc. where errors will and are expected to happen from time-to-time. It’s heavier on runtime environment to handle an exception, than for you to write good code and utilising the given language’s features such ifs or ternary operation.

try catches are not the first line of defense, they are the last line using defensive coding practises.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not repeating what many people have already said, but there's a big advantage of using exceptions which I'd like to mention:

If some routine fails, you can easily decide **on which level of indirection you should handle that exception** - and you won't need to bloat the deeper levels with error checking after, say, each step.

Of course that doesn't free you from the responsibility of having good cleanup code which will leave everything clear for every possible path of execution: so release any resources, sockets, commit or rollback transactions, etc. And there are many means to do that:

- `try... finally` blocks, allowing any exception to propagate but cleaning everything up before (many languages, including Python),
- the `with` statement (specific to Python),
- the RAII paradigm which involves cleanup in destructors (mostly C++).

Answer (score 1):

Especially as you work with large applications, exception handling really is a better practice.  As you mentioned, you are getting a lot of if statements.  With python, using try/except statements allows you to create a more standardized way of dealing with exceptions. With exceptions, you'll get the benefit of seeing the type of exception class as well as any other custom ones you build.  It just gives you a much more structured way of coding.